# Sum-epimorphisms and prod-monomorphisms

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, banach-algebras

> **Sum-epimorphisms**

A longer time ago I have introduced the bi-onto maps for the topological category. Let me formulate here its general categorical definition:

**DEFINITION 1**   A morphism $\ f:X\rightarrow Y\ $ is a sum-epimorphism $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ for every direct sum decomposition $\ (i_A:A\rightarrow X\ \,\ i_B:B\rightarrow X)\ $ at least one of the morphisms $\ f\circ i_A:A\rightarrow Y\ $ or $\ f\circ i_B:B\rightarrow Y\ $ is an epimorphisms.

**QUESTION 1**   Do you know any appearance of sum-epimorphisms in any specific category or in general theory of categories in literature (besides my own obscure paper or possibly two)?

> TOPOLOGICAL ILLUSTRATIONS of topological sum-epimorphisms (i.e. the old bi-onto maps):

**EXAMPLE 1**   Let $\ E\ $ be the Paul Erdős space of rational points of the Hilbert space $\ \ell^2.\ $ Then there exists a (continuous, of course) bi-onto map $\ f:E\rightarrow [0;1].\ $ Since $\ E\ $ is totally disconnected, this result is not obvious (try it, it'd be more than a *mood improvement*).

More generally:

**THEOREM 1**   A continuous map $\ f:X\rightarrow [0;1]\ $ is universal $\ \Leftrightarrow\ f\ $ is bi-onto.

Thus the above EXAMPLE is a corollary to the above theorem. We also have

**THEOREM 2**   If $\ f:X\rightarrow [0;1]\ $ is a bi-onto map of a Hausdorff space $\ X,\ $ then function $\ f\ $ is universal.

**COROLLARY 1**   There does not exist any bi-onto map of the Cantor compact space  $\ \{0\ 1\}^{\aleph_0}\ $ into $\ [0;1].$

> **Prod-monomorphisms**

The dual definition seems to be of interest in the case of Banach spaces:

**DEFINITION 2**   A morphism $\ f:X\rightarrow Y\ $ is a prod-monomorphism $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ for every direct product decomposition $\ (p_A:Y\rightarrow A\ \,\ p_B:Y\rightarrow B)\ $ at least one of the morphisms $\ p_A\circ f:A\rightarrow Y\ $ or $\ p_B\circ f:Y\rightarrow B\ $ is a monomorphism.

**QUESTION 2** Given a non-zero Banach algebra $\ X,\ $ is it true that $\ X\ $ cannot be decomposed into a sum (i.e. categorical product) of two non-zero algebras $\ \Leftrightarrow\ $ every monomorphism $\ C([0;1])\rightarrow X\ $ is a prod-monomorphism?

The question holds both for the real and the complex case.

> It goes without saying that you're most welcome to post here your original results too; then of course publish them in arXiv and so on :-)

Comment: **Please** don't call them **bi-**.  This prefix is already standardly used for "both the idea and its dual", eg *bi-product*, and "2-dimensional with weak equations", eg *bi-category*.

Comment: @PaulTaylor -- which one was first? I will change the name for bi-epimorphism (there used to be bicompact spaces in Russian which meant doubly-compact, i.e. larger then metric compacta wbich used to be simply compacta). Thank you Paul for letting me know about the possible conflict of terminology (now avoided thanks to you).

Comment: Both uses of bi- are very old. If the identity has your property then $X$ is coproduct-irreducible. Your property doesn't have a neat diagram or seem to make much sense in terms of sheaves or factorisations. I feel it is mis-conceived.

Comment: The more mis-conceived the better it is. :-) It does work very nicely for the topological case. I'll add another separate topological ***question*** which illustrates the sum-epimorphisms. And right here above, I'll add a question about prod-monomorphisms for Banach algebras.

Comment: So for the latter question about "direct product decomposition" you assume that $Y\cong A\times B$ if I understand correctly?